# Counting words in a file

Tags: python, file, filenames

I am trying to write a function which will count the numbers of words in a file. But for some reason when I run it an error occurs:

```
def wc(filename):
    """returns the number of words in file filename."""
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    total = 0
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        n = len(words)
        total = total + int(n)
    return total
```

The error says filename is undefined.

The file name is `alice`. When I type in `wc(alice.txt)` in the console on the bottom right hand side, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'alice' is not defined
```

I have saved the file on a usb drive along with the Python file.

Comment: The error is not in your function (assuming it's the _exact_ code your are running). Please post the whole traceback (or just read it, it will tell you exactly where the error occurs).

Comment: Your code works just fine for me on Python 2.7.

Comment: You could be getting a None or empty value for the filename parameter

Comment: sidenote: len(words) is int, you don't need to cast it to int; you may iterate over opened file itself, it will yield the same lines, instead of reading of all the lines first; better to use with statement to open/close management; open with `'rb'` mode for better cross-platform experience.

Comment: Please make sure you have passed the correct file name with correct relative or absolute path. Take special attention if you are not in a Windows environment. File names can be case sensitive. :)

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. Post the error traceback as well as code you are calling this function from.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is how you are calling the function. If you use:

```
wc(alice.txt)
```

You'll probably get an error because `alice.txt` tells python to look for an object named `alice` in your current environment and then try to look up a `txt` attribute on it. If no such object or attribute exist, you'll get an error.

What you want to do instead is pass `alice.txt` to your function as a string. To do this you need to put it in quotation marks:

```
wc("alice.txt")
```

Comment: I have put the text file in the same folder and it does work thanks. do I always need to put it in the same folder?

Comment: The issue you were having had nothing to do with the file itself. It can be located anywhere, but if it's not in the folder you're running your script from, you'll need to specify the path to the file in your string (like `r"c:\Some Folder\Alice.txt"` or `"../alice.txt"`, depending on your OS and how you want to refer to the path).

Answer (score 0):

```
def wc(filename):
    ## Your stuff here
```

This `function` takes `one arguement`, which is `filename`
So, you are required to pass `filename` to this function
along with `relative` or `absolute path`

Suppose your filename is `test_input.txt` and which is in current
working directory,

```
print wc('test_input.txt')
```

if your file is not in the current working directory

```
print wc('/path/to/your/file/test_input.txt')
```